# C# modify app.config

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, app-config

i want to change application settings at runtime, here part of it:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <OPCClient.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="Client_Service" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://localhost/test/service.asmx</value>
        </setting>
    </OPCClient.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

i want to modify this value, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class. The linked MSDN article gives an extensive example on its use, and it allows you to achieve exactly what you are wanting to do.

Also, a worthy note is that you need to add a reference to `System.configuration.dll` in your project to make use of the class.

Comment: i know about configurationmanager, but it doesnt show me this value

Comment: @eba - Do you have access to changing the form of the configuration file?

Comment: yes, but now i can not change its form, because its used by another code in app

Comment: i can not delete <OPCClient.Properties.Settings>